# Order by CASE with different column values in Laravel does not work

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to build a Laravel query which should **order values** by more columns:

first of all, by hour and this works and also by values in a column named "competition_type" in this way:

1. 'ATP - SINGLES'
2. 'WTA - SINGLES'
3. 'CHALLENGER MEN - SINGLES'
4. 'CHALLENGER WOMEN - SINGLES'
5. 'ITF MEN - SINGLES'
6. 'ITF WOMEN - SINGLES'

I tried this query, but it does work...I tried several approaches and this is my last one:

```php
$matches = Match::select()
           ->where('date', $date)->where('pick_score', '<>', '0');

$matches = Match::where('date', $date)
           ->where('pick_score', '<>', '0');

$matches = Match::select("CASE 
           WHEN competition_type like '%ATP - SINGLES%' then 1
           WHEN competition_type like '%WTA - SINGLES%' then 2 
           WHEN competition_type like '%CHALLENGER MEN - SINGLES%' then 3
           WHEN competition_type like '%CHALLENGER WOMEN - SINGLES%' then 4
           WHEN competition_type  '%ITF MEN - SINGLES%' then 5
           WHEN competition_type = '%ITF WOMEN - SINGLES%' then 6 
           END DESC")
           ->select('matches.*');
```

The thing is that if I add an "order by" before the case, it gives me an error. How should I change my query in order to have the column values in the way I mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `selectRaw` for that kind of query.

```php
$matches = Match::selectRaw('CASE
    WHEN competition_type LIKE "%ATP - SINGLES%" THEN 1
    WHEN competition_type LIKE "%WTA - SINGLES%" THEN 2
    WHEN competition_type LIKE "%CHALLENGER MEN - SINGLES%" THEN 3
    WHEN competition_type LIKE "%CHALLENGER WOMEN - SINGLES%" THEN 4
    WHEN competition_type LIKE "%ITF MEN - SINGLES%" THEN 5
    WHEN competition_type LIKE "%ITF WOMEN - SINGLES%" THEN 6
    END
AS type_number')
->orderBy('type_number', 'asc')
->get();
```

Or maybe you want to use an `ORDER BY CASE` query? In that situation, maybe you should try the [`orderByRaw`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#raw-methods) method.

```
$matches = Match::orderByRaw('CASE
    WHEN competition_type LIKE "%ATP - SINGLES%" THEN 1
    WHEN competition_type LIKE "%WTA - SINGLES%" THEN 2
    WHEN competition_type LIKE "%CHALLENGER MEN - SINGLES%" THEN 3
    WHEN competition_type LIKE "%CHALLENGER WOMEN - SINGLES%" THEN 4
    WHEN competition_type LIKE "%ITF MEN - SINGLES%" THEN 5
    WHEN competition_type LIKE "%ITF WOMEN - SINGLES%" THEN 6
    END DESC')
->get();
```